# height: fit-content not stretching to fit inner li

Tags: html, css

I am no css expert so please bear with me. I am trying to make a custom dropdown with its height to fit the number of `li` dynamically. My current code will not fit the `li` even though the dropdown height is set to `fit-content`. How can I fix this?

**EDIT**: I didn't use the min-height property because I want the dropdown to fit the content seamlessly wether it contains 2 `li`'s or 50 `li`'s

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%x;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: green;
}

.dropdownCon {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 50px;
}

.dropdownBtn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 11px 23px 11px 23px;
  background-color: #121212;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  width: 100%;
  height: fit-content;
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}

.dropdown ul {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}

.dropdown ul li {
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 10px;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="dropdownCon">
    <div class="dropdownBtn">
      dropdown
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <ul>
        <li>
          test
        </li>
        <li>
          test
        </li>
        <li>
          test
        </li>
        <li>
          test
        </li>
        <li>
          test
        </li>
        <li>
          test
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove `overflow` statement?

Comment: @Paulie_D I need overflow cause I want the dropdown to be scrollable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: I deleted the first solution because it didn't answer the question. Additionally, I added an improved solution at the bottom based on the comment on this answer.

If you want to keep the scrollbar, you should set the dropdown to some minimum numerical height so that it's not squished. `fit-content` does not work because the `overflow-y: auto` makes it assume the least possible height to make it scrollable, if that makes sense.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%x;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: green;
}

.dropdownCon {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 50px;
}

.dropdownBtn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 11px 23px 11px 23px;
  background-color: #121212;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}

.dropdown ul {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}

.dropdown ul li {
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 10px;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="dropdownCon">
    <div class="dropdownBtn">
      dropdown
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <ul>
        <li>
          test
        </li>
        <li>
          test
        </li>
        <li>
          test
        </li>
        <li>
          test
        </li>
        <li>
          test
        </li>
        <li>
          test
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***Improved answer***
Based on your comment, here's a better suggestion: Don't set `min-height` or `overflow` on the dropdown container itself at all. Instead, set `overflow-y: auto` on the actual `<ul>`. That way, it *does* start off with having the `<ul>` match the height of its content, and you can configure the maximum height using `max-height`. Examine the snippet below and you'll see that `<ul>`'s maximum height is controlled by `max-height`, but other than that, it just fits its content.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%x;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: green;
}

.dropdownCon {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 50px;
}

.dropdownBtn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 11px 23px 11px 23px;
  background-color: #121212;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  width: 100%;
/*   min-height: fit-content;
  overflow-y: auto; */
  background-color: blue;
}

.dropdown ul {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
    /* SEE HERE */
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 100px;
}

.dropdown ul li {
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 10px;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="dropdownCon">
    <div class="dropdownBtn">
      dropdown
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <ul>
        <li>
          test
        </li>
        <li>
          test
        </li>
        <li>
          test
        </li>
        <li>
          test
        </li>
        <li>
          test
        </li>
        <li>
          test
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your second method is what I am looking for but say I only have 2 ```li``` then if I set a minimum height of 100px there will be a lot of empty space in the dropdown container. That's why I didn't use min-height. What do you suggest so that having 2 ```li``` or 50 ```li``` the dropdown will seamlessly fit the content?

Comment: @seriously Ah, I understand. I edited my answer to show exactly what you just asked for. Instead of setting the overflow and height on the dropdown container, set it on the actual `<ul>` element itself. And instead of using `min-height`, you can control the maximum height using `max-height`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: yeah this is what I wanted thanks for the help